# How to remove comma from end of line in CSV file while exporting using C#

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, csv

I am trying to export data from gridview to csv file. I searched it on google and i got some good examples as well. But when i open my generated csv file in notepad, i always get extra comma at the end of each record. I want to remove that comma... Can you please help me here...

Here my code on click of csv button

```
Protected Sub btnexptocsv_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnexptocsv.Click
    Try
        Response.Clear()
        Response.Buffer = True
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
        "attachment;filename=Complaint_Details.csv")
        Response.Charset = ""
        Response.ContentType = "application/text"

        grd_ComplaintDetails.AllowPaging = False

        Dim sb As StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        For k As Integer = 0 To grd_ComplaintDetails.Columns.Count - 1
            'add separator
            sb.Append(grd_ComplaintDetails.Columns(k).HeaderText + ","c)
        Next
        'append new line
        sb.Append(vbCr & vbLf)
        For i As Integer = 0 To grd_ComplaintDetails.Rows.Count - 1
            For k As Integer = 0 To grd_ComplaintDetails.HeaderRow.Cells.Count - 1
                'add separator
                'sb.Append(grd_ComplaintDetails.Rows(i).Cells(k).Text + ","c)
                sb.Append(grd_ComplaintDetails.Rows(i).Cells(k).Text.Replace(",", "") + ",")
            Next
            'append new line
            sb.Append(vbCr & vbLf)
        Next
        Response.Output.Write(sb.ToString())
        Response.Flush()
        Response.End()
    Catch ex As Exception
        div_Msg.InnerText = "Can not generate CSV file"
    End Try

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance... :)

Comment: your code Seems like vb rather than c#

Comment: Why can't you use TrimEnd(",")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make following changes in your code

```
 Protected Sub btnexptocsv_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnexptocsv.Click
    Try
        Response.Clear()
        Response.Buffer = True
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Complaint_Details.csv")
        Response.Charset = ""
        Response.ContentType = "application/text"

        grd_ComplaintDetails.AllowPaging = False

        Dim sbFile As StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        Dim sb As StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        For k As Integer = 0 To grd_ComplaintDetails.Columns.Count - 1
            'add separator
            sb.AppendFormat(",{0}", grd_ComplaintDetails.Columns(k).HeaderText)
        Next
        'append new line
        sb.Remove(0, 1)
        sb.Append(vbCr & vbLf)
        sbFile.Append(sb.ToString())
        For i As Integer = 0 To grd_ComplaintDetails.Rows.Count - 1
            sb = New System.Text.StringBuilder()
            For k As Integer = 0 To grd_ComplaintDetails.HeaderRow.Cells.Count - 1
                'add separator
                sb.AppendFormat(",{0}", grd_ComplaintDetails.Rows(i).Cells(k).Text.Replace(",", ""))
            Next
            sb.Remove(0, 1)
            'append new line
            sb.Append(vbCr & vbLf)
            sbFile.Append(sb.ToString())
        Next
        Response.Output.Write(sbFile.ToString())
        Response.Flush()
        Response.End()
    Catch ex As Exception
        div_Msg.InnerText = "Can not generate CSV file"
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you could do:

1. String.TrimEnd(",")
2. String.Join(",",String[])

Answer (score 0):

Just check if k is less than the total number of columns:

```
For k As Integer = 0 To grd_ComplaintDetails.HeaderRow.Cells.Count - 1
     If k < grd_ComplaintDetails.HeaderRow.Cells.Count - 1 Then
          sb.Append(grd_ComplaintDetails.Rows(i).Cells(k).Text.Replace(",", "") + ",")
     Else
          sb.Append(grd_ComplaintDetails.Rows(i).Cells(k).Text.Replace(",", ""))
     End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try to decrease length by 1 on the StringBuilder

```
sb.Length = sb.Length - 1
```

You can view the output here -> http://dotnetpad.net/ViewPaste/P9wkTEYE-UuquTeVUmwKug

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use a csv field converter.  In its simplest form:

```
"\"" " field.Replace("\"", "\"\") + "\""
```

Quotes are optional, but they allow you to have commas and crs and linefeeds in the field.  Then you don't have to replace them.

Gather them up into an array -- using a linq function would be awesome here -- and then join them (ala Juann):

```
String.Join(",", field.select(m => "\"" + field.Replace("\"", "\"\") + "\"") + "\r\n";
```

Obviously convert this to VB.